# How can I position several images on a diagonal line between opposite corners of the browser window?

Tags: css, positioning

This is exactly what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

So, if I'm not clear, I want those thumbnails to be positioned oblique according to the browser width and height. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to use javascript code like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('.sample').each(function(){
        var this_index = $(this).index();
        var margin_left = $(this).width() * this_index;
        $(this).css({
            marginLeft : margin_left
        });
    });
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
a.sample {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    display:block;
    background-color:red;

     border-radius:50px;
    -moz-border-radius:50px;
     border:2px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<a href="#" class="sample"></a>
<a href="#" class="sample"></a>
<a href="#" class="sample"></a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning with percentage values like in [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/ULWtk/3/).

As for the line, you probably will need to use a canvas for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not so easy, but some ideas to realize this:

1. Create a normal `div` and make it oblique with CSS. [Some informations how you can do this.](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-text-rotation)
2. Render a new image. For example with PHP and gd lib. [About PHP and GD.](http://php.net/manual/de/book.image.php)
3. Use JavaScript or something else to calculate the positions dynamically.